# Is there a way to do reverse search of vim mappings?

Tags: vim

**Is it possible to search mappings by the target command?**

E.g: I would like to search which are the key sequences mapped to `StripWhitespace`.

I know you can search what is mapped to a key sequence using `map {lhs}` command. E.g:

```
map ,s
```

will show mappings to key sequences starting with `,s`:

```
x  ,s            :StripWhitespace<CR>
n  ,sb         * :SortBlock<CR>
```

What I want to do is do the reverse of that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `:filter` sort of like using grep in the shell.

```
:filter /StripWhitespace/ map
```

`:filter` is new in Vim 8 so you have to have a relatively up-to-date Vim. You could also in theory use `execute()` however that is relatively new as well.

Older Vim version you will need to use `:redir`

```
:redir @"> | silent map | redir END | new | put | v/StripWhitespace/d_
```

For more help see:

```
:h :filter
:h execute()
:h :redir
:h :silent
:h :map
:h :new
:h :put
:h :v
:h :d
:h "_
```